# Ошибка при работе с указателями: Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)

Tags: linux, c, указатели

Файл my_funcs.h

```
#ifndef MY_FUNCS_H
#define MY_FUNCS_H

typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    double weight;
}point;

typedef struct{
    point *points;
    int size;
}space;

point* init_space(int size);
void show_points(space *my_space);


#endif
```

Файл my_funcs.c

```
  #include "my_funcs.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

point* init_space(int size){
    point tmpPoints[size];
    for(int i=0; i<=size; i++){
        tmpPoints[i].x = -100 + rand() % 100;
        tmpPoints[i].y = -100 + rand() % 100;
        tmpPoints[i].z = -100 + rand() % 100;
        tmpPoints[i].weight = -100 + rand() % 100;
    }
    space mySpace = {};
    mySpace.size = size;
    mySpace.points = &tmpPoints;
    return &tmpPoints;
}

void show_points(space *my_space){
    printf("Function works\n");
    printf(my_space -> size);
}
```

Файл main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_funcs.h"

#define SIZE_OF_SPACE 5

int main(){
printf("Progarm started...\n");

int size = SIZE_OF_SPACE;
printf("%d%s",size,"\n");
space my_space;
my_space.size = SIZE_OF_SPACE;
my_space.points = init_space(SIZE_OF_SPACE);

printf("%d",my_space.size);

show_points(&my_space);
//printf("YOU ARE HERE!!!!!!\n");
return 0;
}
```

При вызове функции show_points вылетает следующее: "Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)". Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Классика - возврат указателя на локальную переменную...

```
point* init_space(int size){
    point tmpPoints[size];
    ....
    return &tmpPoints;
}
```

После завершения функции `tmpPoints` благополучно исчезает, а его адрес остается в `my_space.points`, и вы им пытаетесь пользоваться.

P.S. А что должно означать вот это странное телодвижение в `init_space`:

```
space mySpace = {};
mySpace.size = size;
mySpace.points = &tmpPoints;
```

Зачем? ведь `mySpace` у вас нигде не используется?

Comment: И плюс к этому выход за границы массива `for(int i=0; i<=size; i++)`

Comment: Тоесть,в данном случае лучше возвращать сам объект, а не ссылку на него? 

Эти 3 строчки остались из первого варианта функции, забыл удалить, в том варианте я возвращал mySpace.